# Как внедрить в картинку кнопки?

Tags: html, javascript, css

Как внедрить в картинку кнопки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Навесить через абсолютное позиционирование на картинку сверху кнопки и всё. Чистый css-html и никакой магии ;)

Answer (score 0):

iwowa, Вы уточните свой вопрос. Если Вам нужна картинка, часть которой функционально является кнопкой, то подходящее решение - ImageMap. Если Вам нужна html-кнопка, отображаемая поверх картинки, то делать надо через позиционирование средствами css.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" style="position:absolute">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<button><img src="/m/default/media/images/feed-icon-small.png"></button>
```

так?

Comment: Нужно наооборот не картинку в кнопку а кнопку в картинку

Answer (score -1):

Если картинка наложена на фон, то кнопку нужно просто позиционировать как обычный html элемент, а если в контейнере есть тег img (т.е картинка), тогда нужно кнопке задать position:absolute, а родительскому контейнеру position:relative(чтоб кнопка позиционировалась от родителя) и двигать ее куда надо с помощью top,left. Но по возможности лучше картинку наложить на background.